# when I return the pdf file to the request, I get an error ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, io

I have a controller with the get method and when accessing this controller I need to enter some data from the existing pdf file (template) to return this file. When I return this pdf file to the request, I get an error:

> ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream

```cs
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(templateFilePath);
Rectangle rect = reader.GetPageSize(1);
var fs = new MemoryStream();
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs))
{
    // modify the pdf content
    PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
    cb.SetColorStroke(iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.GREEN);
    cb.SetLineWidth(5f);
    cb.Circle(rect.GetLeft(1) + 30, rect.GetBottom(1) + 30, 20f);
    cb.Stroke();
}

reader.Close();
fs.Position = 0;
return File(fs, "application/pdf", "newFile");
```

Comment: `PdfStamper` takes ownership of the reader passed to it, don't attempt to close it explicitly - it's already been done.

Answer (score 0):

```
var reader = new PdfReader(templatePath);
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            var pageSize = reader.GetPageSize(1);
            byte[] bytes;
            using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms))
            {
                var canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
                var bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontPath, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

                //Date
                canvas.BeginText();
                canvas.SetFontAndSize(bf, 10);

                canvas.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT,
                    $"10/30/2018",
                    pageSize.GetRight(Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(26)),
                    pageSize.GetTop(Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(20.

                canvas.EndText();

                stamper.Close();
                bytes = ms.ToArray();
            }

            return File(bytes, "application/pdf", "payment.pdf");
```